# How I relate Census Blocks to FIPS Division/Subdivisions

Tags: census, united-states

I need to be able to relate a Census Block to it's corresponding FIPS Division and Subdivision and I have not found any data file or reference to help me identify that relationship, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [FACES](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/FACES/) instead. It has all subdivisions.

Answer (score 2):

TIGER Census Block Data tables contains a field "GEOID" which is a combination of State Fips, County Fips, Census Tract, and Blocks.

ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/TABBLOCK/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, as stated in my original question the details about State/County FIPS are not enough I need the Town/Subdivision also.

Comment: In 2008, NIST withdrew the FIPS 55-3 database. This database included 5-digit numeric place codes for cities, towns, and villages, or other centers of population in the United States. The codes were assigned alphabetically to places within each state, and as a result changed frequently in order to maintain the alphabetical sorting. NIST replaced these codes with the more permanent GNIS Feature ID, maintained by the U.S. Board on Geographic Names.